# Template object in template

Tags: c++, templates, syntax

I want to have a template with parameters typename T and an object of the type T that represents a null_object. The goal is to make a container class in which, for each type, a given null_value is provided for the empty constructor. E.g.

```
template<typename T, T null_value>
class MyObject {
private:
     std::array<T,4> data;

public:
    MyObject() {
        data.fill(null_value);
    }
};
```

However, I cannot do this with the given syntax above. How can I accomplish this? If this is not possible with nested templates, is there a way to define distinct constructors for some given template values? E.g.

```
template<typename T>
class MyObject {
private:
    std::array<T,4> data;

public:
    MyObject<int>() {
        data.fill(0);
    }

    MyObject<float>() {
        data.fill(0.0f);
    }

    MyObject<char>() {
        data.fill('a');
    }
};
```

EDIT:
For some types like `int`, the first chunk of code will compile. However, for types such as `float`, the chunk will not compile.

Comment: On what grounds can you not do this with the given syntax above? https://godbolt.org/z/6MhGE9qKn seems fine. Are you seeing a compiler error? If so, which?

Comment: Some types (_e.g._ `float`) cannot be used as template parameters.

Comment: @paddy good point; author is correct to indicate a problem, I'm wrong to query.

Comment: Correct. When testing the compilation, I used float and got an error.

Comment: Is the `null_value` used anywhere outside the constructor? If not, you can either templatize the ctor or pass it as a (default) parameter.

Comment: it does compile in c++20 https://godbolt.org/z/EjPardaEz

Comment: for code that does not compile you should better include the error message, if only to avoid misunderstandings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is 'how to pick a fill value based on type' then I would suggest you either:

```
MyObject() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        data.fill(0);
    } 
    ... etc ...
}
```

Or else get the value from a secondary template:

```
template <typename T> struct DefaultValue {};
template <> struct DefaultValue<int> { static constexpr int value = 0; };
template <> struct DefaultValue<float> { static constexpr float value = 0.0f; };
// ... etc ...

template<typename T>
class MyObject {
public:
    MyObject() {
        data.fill(DefaultValue<T>::value);
    }
```

Comment: In the second chunk of code, is the `private:` section inside the declaration of the `MyObject` class? I did not know that you can template objects in a template.

Comment: @BENG apologies, no, poorly formed. You can template objects in a template, but you can't provide explicit specialisations, as those have to be at namespace scope. Edited to be properly formed.